# Selecting multiple records by key with Group By

Tags: mysql

For example i have database table 'records':

```
ID - RelationshipID - Country - Val

1 - 88 - UK - 6
2 - 88 - UK - 8
```

--- COUNTRY CHANGES, MAX 8 - MIN 6 = 2. So i want row from my select 88 - UK - 2

```
3 - 88 - FR - 9
4 - 88 - FR - 11
```

--- COUNTRY CHANGES, MAX 11 - MIN 9 = 2. So i want row from my select 88 - FR - 2

```
5 - 88 - UK - 12
6 - 88 - UK - 13
```

--- FINISH, MAX 13 - MIN 12 = 1. So i want row from my select 88 - UK - 1

What i need is to select records grouped by RelationshiopID and country and minused max val from min val by country **BEFORE country changes**.

What I want to get:

```
88 - UK - 2
88 - FR - 2
88 - UK - 1
```

For the best scenario my wish is:

```
88 - UK - 3
88 - FR - 2
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain what is *minused max val from min val by country*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a block number to detect a change in country and then group

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ID int, RelationshipID int, Country varchar(2), Val int);
insert into t values
(1 , 88 , 'UK' , 6),
(2 , 88 , 'UK' , 8),
(3 , 88 , 'FR' , 9),
(4 , 88 , 'FR' , 11),
(5 , 88 , 'UK' , 12),
(6 , 88 , 'UK' , 13);

select block,country,min(val) minval,max(val) maxval,
         max(val) - min(val) diff
from
(
select t.*,
         if(country<>@country,@block:=@block+1,@block:=@block) block,
         @country:=country
from t
cross join (select @block:=0,@country:='') b
order by id
) s
group by s.block,s.country;

+-------+---------+--------+--------+------+
| block | country | minval | maxval | diff |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+------+
| 1     | UK      |      6 |      8 |    2 |
| 2     | FR      |      9 |     11 |    2 |
| 3     | UK      |     12 |     13 |    1 |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+------+
3 rows in set (0.093 sec)
```

If you want the first and last value in each block then get the min and max ids in the sub query and join t grouping by block and country

```
select a.block,a.country,a.minid,a.maxid,
         sum(case when t.id = maxid then val else 0 end) -
         sum(case when t.id = minid then val else 0 end) diff
from t
join
(select block,country,min(id) minid,max(id) maxid
from
(
select t.*,
         if(country<>@country,@block:=@block+1,@block:=@block) block,
         @country:=country
from t
cross join (select @block:=0,@country:='') b
order by id
) s
group by s.block,s.country
) a on t.id =a.minid or t.id = a.maxid
group by a.block,a.country
;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. It helped me but maybe do you have any ideas how I can get FIRST - LAST val before country changes without min max? Because in some cases min max wont be good for me because val is moving up and down.

Comment: You solution works perfectly and fast for me but I have one more question. For example, last VAL of first block is 9, ant the first VAL of second block is 11. Sum of first block is 20. Is there any chance to take that diff (11-9 = 2) and add it to first block that would give me sum of first block = 22. Now i run one more select for selecting first ID of every block and check it for the latest value where ID < selected block FIRST id

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT RelationShipID, Country, SUM(Val)
    FROM records
GROUP BY RelationShipID, Country
```

Comment: Then I get
88 - UK - 27 / 88 - FR - 20

Comment: I see that now. How do you calculate the third column?

Comment: MAX(val) - MIN(val) before country changes. I think that I need TMP table with values from 'What i want to get' and then I could select SUM from that table by country and relationship ID.

Comment: Does the countries always come in pairs, so there are always two rows for each country, where id is increased by one?